# Change website access from everyone from 8am to midnight EST to just my IP from midnight to 8am

Tags: php, apache, cron

I have a question because I don't know exactly where to start looking for answers.
Web details:  Apache 5.3, Linux 3.2 kernel, Ubuntu 12.04, Mysql 5.5, PHP 5.3 on a VPN.

I am currently controlling access to this website via the /etc/httpd.conf file.  (Deny,Allow, Deny from all and then Allow from MY IP).  Also, the site has a commercial SSL certificate.

When the website goes "live" I want it to automatically switch at 8:00 AM EST to "allow all - the public", and then at midnight switch to "allow only me".

I can't quite figure out where to start my investigation:  cron?  Apache coding? php coding?
What?

Suggestions anyone?

Comment: A way but not secured is to make 2 htaccess files (writable) and your cron to replace them at exact time when you want..

Comment: you can create two cron tasks, one to be run on 8:00 am, and one at midnight, the first one removes the restrictions (consider .htaccess file will empty it), the second one (at midnight) adds some lines to .htaccess :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without cron job and without making .htaccess writable using  these .htaccess codes.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} >00
    RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} <08
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.255\.123\.255 #replace this with your IP
    RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

Above code will work for you and it's a better idea to also show a message to your visitors.

Comment: Thank all!! You've all given me much food for thought!!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than modifying apache configs, i'd suggest a cron job that modifies ip tables rules. That way users dont hit your site, and you dont need to worry that people might be getting 404's or something similar.

Of course, it also depends on how you want to end the session for people that are currently browsing - ie, using iptables or apache config changes will mean that someone might be half way through something and suddenly get 403's.

If you want to provide a friendly "down for maintenance" message, you might also want to consider using rewrites to redirect visitors to a maintenance page, advising users when the site will be available again.

Coding it into your application could allow you to give people a few minutes to finish what they are doing (ie a page notice advising users that they x minutes to finish what they are doing before they get forcibly removed).

And you could combine the two options: at 23:55, a banner is displayed advising people the site will be unavailable from 00:00 - 08:00, and then use iptables/apache configs/rewrites to restrict access.

Another thought, if you have a site with public content, you may see issues with search crawlers - ie they can only hit the site intermittently, which may have an impact somehow. (assuming you want to reach as many people as possible, getting your pages indexed by search engines would be important).

**edit** @amit- that solution is great, and now that i am aware of it, i would definately suggest that is a better alternative. I would however avoid putting in a .htaccess unless you have no other choice (see [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html#when) for further details about when (not) to use .htaccess)

Comment: Mark - I would use the httpd.conf file to implement any changes.